# There is not active server - atom-ternjs

Tags: javascript, package, installation, atom-editor, ternjs

last I installed atom-ternjs for my Atom editor. If i want to configure it I get message

> "There is not active server".

I tried to set up this package manualy but I get the same message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you must open any javascript file first.

Answer (score 0):

install script package
command + i
packages->atom ternjs->config